# Why doesn't the else part of this code run?

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know if I am missing something but there is something wrong with this code. When I leave the input area blank the else part should run, but it does not. Can someone explain me why?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p> Put your name and see what happens. </p>

<input id="nameinput">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click To See Your Name</button>
<p id="namedemo"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">

   function myFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById("nameinput") != "") {
        var u;
        u = document.getElementById("nameinput").value;
        document.getElementById("namedemo").innerHTML = "Your name is " + u;
    }

    else {
        alert("Please fill required field");
    }
}

</script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: `#nameinput` is an input element, how would it be an empty string? Move the definition of `u` above the `if`, and check `u` instead of the element itself.

Comment: Your else statement wiil not fire because you are comparing the element rather than the content of the element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `.value` in your statement, It should be

```
if(document.getElementById("nameinput").value != ""){
```

**Here is a working DEMO :** https://jsfiddle.net/ku7ubhnL/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ahh! Thanks! I was going crazy!

Comment: yeah sure i can